# Is it possible to constrain a C# generic method type parameter as "assignable from" the containing class' type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I suspect the answer is no, but I want to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
public class MyGenericClass<TSomeClass> {
    public void MyGenericMethod<TSomeInterface>() 
        // This doesn't compile.
        where TSomeClass : TSomeInterface 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

What I mean to indicate in the above (non-working) example is to constrain `TSomeInterface` such that it can be any base class, implemented interface, or (if you really want to get fancy) implicit conversion of `MyGenericClass`.

**NOTE:**
I suspect that the reason why this was never implemented in C# is that generic constraints are not *really* meant to be code contracts, which is how I am trying to use them here. I really don't care what type `TSomeInterface` is, so long as it is implemented by `TSomeClass`.

So far, I have hacked this together:

```
public class MyGenericClass<TSomeClass> {
    public void MyGenericMethod<TIntermediateType, TSomeInterface>() 
        where TIntermediateType : TSomeClass, TSomeInterface 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This more or less enforces the constraint that I want (that `TSomeClass` must inherit from, or in the case of an interface, implement, `TSomeInterface`), but calling it is very clumsy, because I have to specify `TIntermediateType` (even though I really want it to evaluate against `TSomeClass`):

```
var myGenericInstance = new MyGenericClass<TSomeClass>();
myGenericInstance.MyGenericMethod(TSomeClass, TSomeInterface);
```

Additionally, the above hack is broken because a caller could in theory specify a subclass of `TSomeClass` as the first type parameter, where only the subclass implements `TSomeInterface`.

**The reason that I want to do this** is that I am writing a fluent factory pattern for a WCF service, and I would *like* to prevent the caller (at compile time) from trying to create an endpoint with a contract that the service class doesn't implement.  I can obviously check this at runtime (WCF in fact does this for me), but I am a big fan of compile-time checking.

Is there a better/more elegant way to achieve what I am after here?

Comment: This is practically impossible since you're trying to mix generics with runtime.

Comment: No, I'm not.  I am just trying to apply a generic constraint that (as far as I can tell) the C# language doesn't allow (constraining a type parameter such that it is a superclass or implemented interface of a type parameter in the containing class).

Comment: As far as i see it, you try to constrain the class generic based on type data you feed to a method. If you want to constrain your class generic you need to do this on a class level (logically) else there is no way for the JIT compiler to create a concrete class.

Comment: I am trying to constrain the method's parameter, but I am doing it backward from the normal order.  Rather than `TSomeInterface` inheriting from or implementing `TSomeClass`, I want it to be constrained to the set of base classes and implemented interfaces of `TSomeClass`.

Comment: Ahh i see now, sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: @RJLohan, please undelete your answer, I think you may be on the right track!

Comment: I assume moving interface up to class `MyGenericClass<TSomeClass,MyGenericClass<TSomeClass>` doesn't work for your case? (would be trival to put the restriction...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it does, and in reality that's almost certainly how I'm going to solve this in my actual codebase.  At this point it is really more of an academic question for me.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that said, there are some real world cases where that wouldn't solve it.  Imagine if you wanted to call N methods on MyGenericClass, where N is arbitrarily > 1, and for each one you want to provide a different interface.

Comment: I see. Can't think of anything bacause there is no relationship between TSomeClass and  TSomeInterface, so there would not be a way to convince compiler otherwise. I though of trying something extra class to call method like `class MethodCaller<T, TI>: where T:TI` and instantiating it with `MethodCaller<TSomeClass, TSomeInterface>` but compiler would not be able to figure out if it ok :(.

Answer (score 3):

The way I was able to wrap my head around the reason why this doesn't compile is the following:

Consider this program compiles:

```
class Program {
    class Class1 { }
    class Class2 { }
    public class MyGenericClass<TSomeClass> {
        public void MyGenericMethod<TSomeInterface>() where TSomeClass : TSomeInterface {
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var inst = new MyGenericClass<Class1>();
    }
}
```

Everything is good. The compiler is happy. Now consider I change the `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var inst = new MyGenericClass<Class1>();
    inst.MyGenericMethod<Class2>();
}
```

The compiler will complain that `Class1` does not implement `Class2`. But **which line is wrong**? The constraint is on the call to `MyGenericMethod`, but the offending line of code is the creation of `MyGenericClass`.

In other words, which one gets the red squiggly line?

Comment: In my ideal world it would be the method call of course, just as it would be if you tried to do this: `var x = new List<String>(); s.Add(5);`.  The compiler assumes the declaration is correct and the method call is using an invalid argument.  +1 for thinking about the syntax though.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596387/constrain-type-parameter-to-a-base-type?lq=1), you can't use a type parameter that isn't from the current declaration, on the left side of a `where` clause.

So as suggested by w0lf in that other question, what you can do is provide both types in your interface (rather than method) declaration:

```
public class MyGenericClass<TSomeClass, TSomeInterface> {
    where TSomeClass : TSomeInterface 
    public void MyGenericMethod() // not so generic anymore :( 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

That, however, greatly limits your `MyGenericMethod` and forces your class to declare before-hand what base interface you with to allow.

So **another option** is to use a static method with more type parameters:

```
public class MyGenericClass<TSomeClass> {
    public static void MyGenericMethod<TSomeClass, TSomeInterface>
                                         (MyGenericClass<TSomeClass> that) 
        where TSomeClass : TSomeInterface 
    {
        // use "that" instead of this
    }
}
```

Possibly you could make it an extension method to make it appear to the user like an actual method.

Neither of these is exactly what you wanted, but probably better than the intermediate type solution.

As for the reason for *why not?*, my guess is that it would complicate the compiler without adding enough value. Here's a [discussion by Angelika Langer of the same subject but about **Java**](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107). Although there are significant differences between C# and Java, I think her conclusion might apply here as well:

> The bottom line is that the usefulness of lower bounds on type
>   parameters is somewhat debatable.  They would be confusing and perhaps
>   even misleading when used as type parameters of a generic class.  On
>   the other hand, generic methods would occasionally profit from a type
>   parameter with a lower bound.   For methods, a work-around for the
>   lack of a lower bound type parameter can often be found. Such a
>   work-around typically involves a static generic method or a lower
>   bound wildcard.

She also gives a nice use case, see the link above.

Answer (score 2):

An extension method provides the best solution, though it doesn't totally solve all your concerns.

```
public class MyGenericClass<TSomeClass>
{
}

public static class MyGenericClassExtensions
{
    public static void MyGenericMethod<TSomeClass, TSomeInterface>(this MyGenericClass<TSomeClass> self)
        where TSomeClass : TSomeInterface
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

It is still necessary to specify both types when calling `MyGenericMethod`, but it prevents the caller from specifying an incorrect type for `TSomeClass` as is possible with the approach you came up with.  With this approach, the method can be called like so:

```
var myGenericInstance = new MyGenericClass<TSomeClass>();
myGenericInstance.MyGenericMethod<TSomeClass, TSomeInterface>();
```

It will be a compile error if the type parameter `MyGenericClass` is declared with does not match the first type parameter to `MyGenericMethod`.

Since the first type parameter can be inferred by the `this` argument, it is often possible for the compiler to infer both type parameters if their additional parameters to the method.