# Constrain type parameter to a base type

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I know how to force a type parameter to be a *subtype* of another type:

```
public interface IMapping<T2> 
{
    public void Serialize<T3>(T3 obj) 
        where T3 : T2;
}
...

var mapping = MapManager.Find<Truck>();
mapping.Serialize(new TonkaTruck());
```

Is there a way to force a type parameter to be a *supertype* of another type?

```
public interface IMapping<T2>
{
    public void IncludeMappingOf<T1>() 
        where T2 : T1;   // <== doesn't work
}
...

var mapping = MapManager.Find<Truck>();

// Truck inherits Vehicle    
// Would like compiler safety here:
mapping.IncludeMappingOf<Vehicle>(); 

mapping.Serialize(new TonkaTruck());
```

Currently, I'm having to compare T1 and T2 at runtime using `IsSubclassOf` inside `IncludeMappingOf`.  A compile-safe solution would be preferable.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Changed the example to be less design-smelly.

**NOTE:** The linked question is quite similar, but no suitable answer is given.  Hopefully this question will shed some light on that one as well.

**EDIT #2:**

Simpler example:

```
public class Holder<T2>
{
    public T2 Data { get; set; }

    public void AddDataTo<T1>(ICollection<T1> coll)
        //where T2 : T1    // <== doesn't work
    {
        coll.Add(Data);   // error
    }
}

...
var holder = new Holder<Truck> { Data = new TonkaTruck() };
var list = new List<Vehicle>();
holder.AddDataTo(list);
```

Compiler: Argument type 'T2' is not assignable to parameter type 'T1'.  *Yes I know that, I'm trying to get the compiler to allow only cases where T2 IS assignable to parameter type T1!*

Comment: Quite an interesting question, however I can't shake the feeling that there might be a design issue here, why doesn't `TruckMapping` inherit `VehiculeMapping` instead of `IMapping` ? I mean it does sound like truck mapping is a specialized version of the more general vehicle mapping or am I missing something ?

Comment: Strongly related (duplicate): [Is it possible to constrain a C# generic method type parameter as “assignable from” the containing class' type parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255558/is-it-possible-to-constrain-a-c-sharp-generic-method-type-parameter-as-assignab)

Comment: @SimonRapilly: Probably right.  This is a contrived example to help illustrate the problem.  I've changed the example up a bit.

Comment: I can't see any real-case scenario when something like that would be helpful. Do you have any?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I'll grant you that the first example was pretty out there.  I've added a more useful scenario.

Comment: @CSJ Sorry but the feeling is bigger with the new example, it's actually clearer now, you have a container `Holder` that you specified should contain at least `T2` objects but you want to add to it objects that are less than that. This goes against the polymorphism principle, `Holder` does the job the asked him to do.

Comment: @SimonRapilly: Not so.  `Holder` has two jobs: (1) to hold some Data that is at least T2, and (2) to add this Data to an external container that can contain T2's, among possibly other things.

Comment: @CSJ I really can't bend my head on how this couldn't break a principle of OOP or being the only or best solution; I guess I need a real live example. Well any case don't let me stop you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extension methods to come close to what you want. Using your holder example it would be:

```
public class Holder<T2>
{
    public T2 Data { get; set; }
}

public static class HolderExtensions
{
    public static void AddDataTo<T2, T1>(this Holder<T2> holder, ICollection<T1> coll)
        where T2 : T1
    {
        coll.Add(holder.Data);
    }
}
```

That then allows your example calling code to compile without error:

```
var holder = new Holder<Truck> { Data = new TonkaTruck() };
var list = new List<Vehicle>();
holder.AddDataTo(list);
```

The mapping example is complicated by the fact that it is an interface.  It may be necessary to add an implementation method to the interface if there is no way to implement the extension method from the existing interface.  That means you will still need a runtime check, but callers can get the good syntax and compile time checking. That would be something like:

```
public interface IMapping<T2>
{
    void IncludeMappingOf(Type type);
}

public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static void IncludeMappingOf<T2, T1>(this IMapping<T2> mapping)
        where T2 : T1
    {
        mapping.IncludeMappingOf(typeof(T1));
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly, the `IncludeMappingOf` does not have a parameter of type `T1` so the type parameters cannot be inferred. You are forced to specify both types when calling it:

```
var mapping = MapManager.Find<Truck>();
mapping.IncludeMappingOf<Truck, Vehicle>();
mapping.Serialize(new TonkaTruck());
```

That can often be worked around by changing the API to include a parameter (i.e. `truckMapping.IncludeMappingOf(vehicleMapping)`), changing which method/class the parameter is on or in fluent APIs creating chains (i.e. `mapping.Of<Vehicle>().Include()`).

Comment: This is very clever, if not a bit inelegant (the logic for my class is now spread over two classes) -- but it does achieve the goal!

Answer (score 5):

While w0lf's answer gives a direct solution, I want to give some background explanation.

When you write something like

```
class C<A> where A : B
```

or

```
void F<A>() where A : B
```

the constraints of the form `A : B` must have `A` as one of the generic type parameters on the class, interface, method, etc. being declared.

The error you are facing is *not* because you've placed a generic type parameter of the current declaration on the right side of the colon (that's legal) - it's because you've placed a generic type parameter of an outer declaration (not of the current declaration) on the left side of the colon.

If you want to form a constraint `A : B` on some declaration, `A` must be introduced on that declaration and the scope of `A` must be less than or equal to the scope of `B`. The reason this is a pragmatic language restriction is that, for any generic type parameter `T`, it isolates any reasoning about constraints on the type `T` to the single declaration where `T` is being introduced.

Comment: Sure, I understand.  But you can see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @CSJ I see what you're trying to achieve, it's very clear. What I'm explaining is that there's a language restriction preventing you from doing that. These language restrictions essentially make the generic type constraint graph a tree which makes reasoning about it easier, at the cost of some expressiveness. You can use w0lf's suggestion as a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Declare both generic types and the generic constraint at class(interface) level:

```
public interface IMapping<T1, T2> where T2 : T1
{
    void IncludeMapping(IMapping<T1, T2> otherMapping);
}
```

Comment: This would mean that any instance of the class must always use a `T3` as declared, whereas the original intent you could declare/instantiate the object, then pass any number of different types into the `Serialize` method so long as `T2` was a derived type. Furthermore, the question was asking to constrain `T2` as a derived type of `T3`, not the other way around. EDIT: Ahh, you just edited your answer. Ignore the second part of my comment.

Comment: You might need to update your edit. You probably ought to not redeclare `<T1, T2>` and its constraints in the interface method; I believe these would be newly declared types that share no relationship with the `<T1, T2>` that are part of the interface declaration.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair you're right; I realized that and updated my answer

Comment: This solution requires the implementor to know up front which base type(s) will be required, and declare the interfaces this way in advance.  It also handcuffs a caller: only one base type (T1) may be used.  What if he wants to proceed to call IncludeMappingOf<T0> as well?